# What is the use or effect of freezing Symbols and Numbers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

In Ruby 1.9 you can have `Fixnum`, `Float`, and `Symbol` values that are unfrozen or frozen:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [ 17, 42.0, :foo ]; a.map(&:frozen?)
=> [false, false, false]

irb(main):002:0> a.each(&:freeze); a.map(&:frozen?)
=> [true, true, true]
```

I understand the utility of freezing strings, arrays, or other mutable data types. As far as I know, however, `Fixnum`, `Symbol`, and `Float` instances are immutable from the start. Is there any reason to freeze them (or any reason that Ruby wouldn't report them as already `frozen?`

*Note that in Ruby 2.0 `Fixnum`s and `Float`s both start off as frozen, while `Symbol`s retain the behavior described above. So, it's slowly getting 'better' :)*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer is no. Those data types are immutable. There is no reason to freeze those datatypes. The reason Ruby does not report those datatypes as frozen is because the [`obj.frozen?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000357) method returns the freeze status of the object and it is set to `false` initially for immutable datatypes. Calling `obj.freeze` will set the `freeze` status to `true` for that object.

The bottom line is that calling `freeze` on an immutable datatype sets the `freeze` status of the obj to `true`, but does nothing because the object is already immutable.